# Limit of fraction of $n^k$ and $|z|^k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $z\in\Bbb{C}$ with $|z|>1, k\in\Bbb{N}$. How do I show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^k}{|z|^n}=0?$$ 
I tried using the squeeze theorem but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If $|z| > 1$ then $|z| = 1+p$ for $p > 0$. Then let $\alpha$ be an integer greater than $k$. For $n > 2 \alpha$

$$(1+p)^n > \dbinom{n}{\alpha}p^{\alpha} = \frac{n(n-1) \ldots (n-\alpha+1)}{\alpha!} > \frac{n^{\alpha}p^{\alpha}}{2^{\alpha}\alpha!}.$$

Hence for large enough $n$,

$$0 < \frac{n^k}{(1+p)^n} < \frac{2^{\alpha}\alpha!}{p^{\alpha}}n^{k- \alpha}.$$

Since $k- \alpha < 0, n^{k-\alpha} \rightarrow 0$ so by the squeeze theorem, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the squeeze theorem successfully on this problem. There is just a little bit of set-up that needs to happen first. We know exponents grow faster than powers, which means given $k \in \Bbb{N}$ there will be a minimal natural number $m$ such that $m^{k+1}\leq |z|^m$. If we know we have our $m$ where $m^{k+1}\leq |z|^m$ then it should also be clear that $m^{k}\leq |z|^m$ and that our inequality is valid for all $n \geq m$. The following should now hold. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{n^k|z|^n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{|z|^n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{k+1}}{|z|^n}$$ By choice of $m$ we know $$\frac{m^{k+1}}{|z|^m} \leq 1  \implies \frac{m^{k}}{|z|^m} \leq \frac{1}{m}$$
Simplifying the inequality involving limits and using the fact that $\frac{n^{k}}{|z|^n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ we have enough to conclude $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{|z|^n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k}{|z|^n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$$